# How can I create a button that submits and redirects to a link(I want it after submitting to direct to another link that says they have submitted)?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect, button

I am new to programming and I am trying to creating a form...In the end I want a button that submits and redirects to another link.
Thank You

I tried the following...

```
<div class= "button">
      <a href="https://www.example.com">  
        <button>Click Me</button>  
      </a>
    </div>
```

This one submits but doesn't redirect

```
 <input type="submit" onClick="myFunction()"/> 

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        window.location.href="http://programminghead.com";  
      }
    </script>
```

```
<form method="POST" action="anotherPage.php">  
      <input type="text"/> 
      <input type="submit"/> 
     </form>
```

These two just redirect they don't submit.
Thank You

Comment: Would you like to do a POST or a GET request? Often you use a POST request if you are going to change something on the backend (like updating a database). Doing a GET request is often used for querying something, like a search where the parameters are in the URL.